# how to get Firebase Firestore exception code on Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

from the documentation in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException.Code) it seems that Firestore have some error codes. how to catch that in Flutter so I can localize the error message

I have tried to use the code below

```
Future<User?> getUser({required String userID}) async {
    try {
      final documentSnapshot = await _db.collection(path).doc(userID).get();

      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        return User.fromFirestore(documentSnapshot.data()!);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } on FirebaseFirestoreException (error) {
      print(error.code);

      // I hope I can get the error.code in here
      
    }
  }
```

but I have error

[image]

Comment: Are you using flutter fire ?

Answer (score 1):

```
_db.collection(path).doc(userID).get()
   .then((e){
    User user = User.fromFirestore(e.data()!);
    }).catchError((err)=> print(err.message));
```